# $ M(X) $ is a Banach space if $ \| \mu \| = | \mu |(X) $. Rudin's book (RCA).

Tags: measure-theory

let $M(X)$ be the space of all complex regular Borel measures on a locally compact hausdorff space $ X $. Prove that is a Banach space if $ \| \mu \| = | \mu |(X) $. Where $ | \mu |$ is the total variation of the complex measure $\mu $.

The idea to solve this exercise is to define an isomorphism $ \Phi : M(X)\longrightarrow C_0 (X)^* $ by

$ \Phi (\mu) = \Lambda $, where $ \Lambda (f) = \int_{X} f d\mu  \;,  \forall f \in C_0 (X) $.

First, I need to show that $\Phi $ is well defined. My difficulty lies in showing that

$ \Lambda \in C_0 (X)^* $.

That is, for each $ \mu \in M(X) $

if $ \Lambda : C_0(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb K  $ is defined by

$ \Lambda (f) = \int_{X} f d\mu  \;,  \forall f \in C_0 (X) $

then $\Lambda $ is a bounded linear functional.

How do I prove that $ |\Lambda (f)| \leq c\| f \|_{C_0 (X)} $?

below are the rest of the definitions [image]

Comment: I need to show that for each $ \mu $, that $ \Lambda = \Phi (\mu) $ is a continuous linear functional. I need to show that $ \Phi $ is well defined.

Comment: It must be the case that $\left.\lvert \int_X f(x)\, d\mu\right\rvert\le \int_X |f(x)|\, d|\mu|.$ I would be surprised if this were not true

Comment: Thank you, I could not use $  |\int_{X} f d\mu | \leq \int_{X} |f| d\mu$ because $\mu$ is a complex measure, but $|\mu|$ is a real measure and $\mu \ll |\mu|$. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

With the observation of Giuseppe Negro,

$ |\Lambda(f) | = |\int_{X} f d\mu | \leq \int_{X} |f| d|\mu|$

$ \hspace{3.6cm}   \leq \int_{X} (sup_{\begin{subarray}{l} x \in C_0(X)
\end{subarray}}|f(x)|) d|\mu| $

$\hspace{3.6cm}  =  \int_{X} ||f||_{C_0(X)} d|\mu| = |\mu|(X)||f||_{C_0(X)}$

set $ c := |\mu|(X) $ we have $ |\Lambda(f) | \leq c||f||_{C_0(X)}  $, then $\Lambda $ is a bounded linear functional.

Comment: That's it. It remains to prove the key step, that is, $|\int f\, d\mu|\le \int |f|\, d|\mu|$. It is surely enough to prove this for $f=\mathbf 1_{A}$ for a measurable $A\subset X$. Then you turn the usual approximation machine: if it is true for such $f$ then it is true for simple functions, and simple functions are dense in the space of continuous functions that vanish at infinity.